# Any way in Angular to re-render or re-compile part of page or whole page that uses one time bindings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have multiple lists on the page that can have hundreds of items so for performance reasons, we'd like to use one-time bindings for things and only update when we know it needs to be updated and significantly reduce the watcher numbers.

If we do use one-time bindings, is there a way to force Angular to re-render part of the page or even the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

So I did some research and there doesn't seem to be a native way of doing this. I did find this possible code to help that could work but when I tried it had issues with some custom 3rd party directives I was using but it might work for other people who want to do simpler things:

https://gist.github.com/kentcdodds/739566ebd3609ac95e61

The only functionality I found that seemed to do what I was looking for was ng-if, which as we know if it goes from true to false then back to true it will remove the element and all angular/scopes when it's set to false and then recompiling and re-adding when set to true (yes that includes rebinding one time bindings!).

I've been working on this as a solution and will post back with how it goes but initial tests do seem promising. Any thoughts or comments on this approach are also welcome.

UPDATE

So I did manage to get this to work. 
Basically you take the element which you want to recompile and rebind and add an ng-if with some sort of "reset" variable like so:

```
<div id="dashboard-view" ng-if="reset">
  ... Some more code that includes one time bindings i.e. {{::store.name}}...
</div>
```

In your controller:

```
angular.module('sampleApp')
  .controller('SampleCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.reset = true;

    $scope.dataUpdated = function(){
        $scope.store.name = "new name";
        $scope.reset = false;
        $timeout(function(){$scope.reset=true;},50);
    };
});
```

Where dataUpdate can be any event handler that causes the data to be updated (for example a form for a new object or a form to update an existing object) your button could be

```
<input type="submit" ng-click=dataUpdated>
```

I'm not sure if the timeout is the best way to do it. When I tried just doing $scope.reset = false; $scope.reset = true; it didn't work. Maybe could try injecting a $scope.$apply() in between them. If anyone has any comments about this please let me know.

But this works and so everything will be recomplied (and also rerendered) and anything with a one-time bind inside the #dashboard-view div will be rebinded if those values were changed.

If anyone has a better solution or way of doing this feel free to answer as well. I hope this helps someone else, it took me a while to come up with this approach .

UPDATE 2
So I did a bit of research into the source-code of ng-if and there's a more advanced concept of transclusion in angular so if anyone is interested in a more pure non-hacky way that would be a good place to start.